# display message when user close browser or navigate to other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm gathering reviews on a page, I want the following functionality:

If user has entered review and close window then they should get message.

If user has not entered review then they should not get message when close window

JavaScript Code:

```
  function WinClose()
  {
    if(document.getElementById('txtReviewDesc').value == '')
        return 'true';
    else
        return 'false';
  }
  window.onbeforeunload = WinClose;
```

Html Elements

```
 <input type="text" id="txtReviewTitle" maxlength="200" autofocus />
 <textarea id="txtReviewDesc" ></textarea>
```

i gives message every time when i close window. I want message only if i have written something in textbox

Comment: Just add an `alert` or whatever to the `WinClose()` function

Comment: i gives alert message every time when i close window. I want message only if i have written something in textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works.

Check this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/shyamchandranmec/CYk8S/

```
<input type="text" id="txtReviewTitle" maxlength="200" autofocus />
<input id="txtReviewDesc" />
```

I have changed your return type from 'true' 'false' to true and false

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your function with:

```
function WinClose() {
    if(document.getElementById('txtReviewDesc').value != '') {
      return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
    }
}
```

See also this doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload

Answer (score 0):

Change `return 'true';`  to `return true` without quotes. Do the same for `return false` as well.